# How to access page controls from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am aware that many of the content pages will create textBox controls with lets say txtCustomerName. And if this is found I need to update the value from session. In this particular case I can not move these controls to master page.

How do you access page controls from master page. And in which event of page life cycle should  we attempt to do this ?

Comment: You cannot rely on that controls exist since you don't know which page is using (or will be using in future) this MasterPage. That is why it's bad practise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find in any Event you would like to, like in this example I am showing you on Button Click Event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox TextBox1 = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
   if (TextBox1 != null)
   {
       Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
   }
}
```

Comment: @SeToY: That's nonsense. The only difference is that `as`-casting will not throw an exception if there's a control with ID `TextBox1` which is not a `TextBox`. It will just return `null`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Can you please let me know if it is right or wrong?

Comment: @Rahul: You can use both ways.

Comment: @SeToY: An exception is only thrown when the cast is invalid.That means if there's a control with that ID wihich is not a `TextBox`.If there's no control with that ID `FindControl` returns `null` and the cast succeeds.